# Mount my OSX Partition manually and read only

Tags: partitioning, mount, mac

I've recently installed Ubuntu 15.10 on a partition of a Macbook Pro. I'm trying to get access to my OSX partition files on the Ubuntu partition. I really just want to play music- pretty simple I thought. But now I'm worried there might be an issue with my mac partition or something. the partition does not auto mount as a read only device in Ubuntu 15.10. I have made the directory /mnt/mac.

Running a simple sudo mount /dev/sda2 command gives me:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

I've installed hfsplus and hfsutils and ran:

```
sudo mount -t hfsplus /dev/sda2 /mnt/mac
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.

sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sda2 /mnt/mac
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.

dmesg | tail
[   11.374605] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   11.374611] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   11.374615] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 3070.215544] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
[ 4912.220704] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
[ 5007.642967] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
[ 5469.323839] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
[ 5560.640138] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
[ 5708.026271] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
[ 6132.163793] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
```

I don't care to write files to my mac so don't find it necessary to remove journaling and such...or is that still necessary just to mount my mac partition as read only?

it seems like this information is commonly asked for in threads related to mounting issues:

```
sudo fdisk -l
...
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1         40    409639    409600   200M EFI System
/dev/sda2     409640 733242175 732832536 349.5G Apple Core storage
/dev/sda3  733242176 734511935   1269760   620M Apple boot
/dev/sda4  734511936 976842879 242330944 115.6G Linux filesystem

sudo gdisk /dev/sda2
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.0

Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm rather new with Ubuntu.

Comment: Clicking on the drive in the file browser doesn't work?

Comment: You may want to boot into OS X, open Disk Utility and Verify the disk.

Comment: there is no drive in the file browser? Are you asking me to verify the disk is sda2?

Answer (score 2):

Core Storage is a logical volume management system OSX. Is the basis for Apple's Fusion Drive technology, which presents several partitions on multiple drives as a single logical volume.

The libfvde package contains a library and applications to read the FileVault Disk Encryption volumes, it contains the following tools:     fvdeinfo, which shows information about FVDE Volumes, and fvdemount, which FUSE mounts FVDE Volumes.

How to build: https://github.com/libyal/libfvde/wiki/Building

How to mount partition: https://github.com/libyal/libfvde/wiki/Mounting

Comment: I can't get the deb files to form. After running

    dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot

I get a few errors and therefore no .deb files are formed. Instead my desktop receives a libfvde_<version>.dsc file and a new libfvde_<version>.tar.gz file

Comment: the GCC seemed to work and obtaining the encrypted root as well, but when I attempted to mount using fvdemount it returned command not found. Clearly something still didn't work. My apologies if I am doing something obvious wrong, your help is appreciated